# How to put the character ] inside the short version of caption on list of table?

Tags: captions, brackets, optional-arguments

I'm using winedt and would like to insert something like

```
\caption [blabla  [-1, 1]V] {blabla  [-1, 1]V...}
```

in one of the tables, but I do not know how to escape the character ].

I've tried `\\]` and `]]` but it does not work.

Is there any one that could help me with this?

Comment: Try to protect it using `\caption[blabla {$[-1, 1]V$}]{blabla $[-1, 1]V$}`. Note that I added `$` since I guess that it is math.

Comment: \caption[{  ...[].....}]{...}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually argument braces help:

```
\caption[{blabla [-1,1]V}]{blabla [-1,1]V...}
```

or (as group braces):

```
\caption[blabla [-1,1{]}V]{blabla [-1,1]V...}
```

Comment: In general the first form is usually better as TeX will remove the braces before typesetting the caption (and they may affect typesetting if the `[]` are in  math)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, but the better first form can fail sometimes due to bugs in the packages, if the argument is passed as optional argument without argument braces, typical error: `\foobar[#1]` instead of `\foobar[{#1}]`.

Comment: Ah yes, packages with bugs, I wouldn't know anything about that:-)